# package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4605 pos 12: '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart

am getting this problem in my home page while calling api in it initally there was not any problem but the upgrade in android studio i got the proble what may be theresion class HomeScreen extends i i press the back buton from any screen the red screen of the picture is shown  i have called jst api in the screen

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).